# tar over ssh: Set destination file name and location, and overwrite existing

Tags: bash, ssh, server, tar, remote-server

The easiest way to explain this question is show the following line of code which I have in a bash script.

```
tar -cJf - ./my_folder | ssh user@example 'tar -xJf - && rm -r ./path-to-my_folder/my_folder && mv ./my_folder ./path-to-my_folder'
```

I don't fully understand how it works. (What does `'-'` mean in this context?) But this is what it does:

- Creates a compressed tar archive in memory and the pipe somehow pushes the tar data over ssh
- The tar archive appears in `user`s root folder, it is extracted
- The ssh command continues executing the stuff in the between `' ... '`, the old folder on the server side is removed using `rm` and replaced by moving the extracted folder from the user's root directory

It is obvious that this is a rather long way of doing things. It would be better if the tar archive was extracted to the correct location so that the `rm` and `mv` commands would not be necessary. Can this be done?

Note: I **cannot** use **rsync**.

Comment: All your tar-over-ssh questions really belong on unix.stackexchange.com or superuser.com. SO is for programming questions, not questions about ordinary command lines.

Comment: @Barmar I agree - I accidentally posted a question on server fault which was the wrong place also. I have flagged it for migration

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Unix & Linux

Comment: Well that doesn't make any sense. Wait for migration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
tar -cJf - ./my_folder | ssh user@example 'tar -xJf - -C path-to-my_folder'
```

The `-` sign mean *STDOUT*. But in modern `tar` implementation, *STDOUT* **is** default output, so `-f -` could be omited:

```
tar -cJ my_folder | ssh user@example 'tar -xJC path-to-my_folder'
```

The `-J` switch mean `xz` compression, wich could be overkill on small configuration (like raspberry-pi, android and many embed systems), so you could obtain better performances by using `-z` switch for `gzip` compression:

```
tar -zc my_folder | ssh user@example 'tar -zxC path-to-my_folder'
```

Comment: Fantastic - thanks! It even appears to overwrite the old contents.