# tar over ssh in combination with sshpass

Tags: bash, ssh, tar, remote-server, sshpass

I (very) recently posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38275929/tar-over-ssh-set-destination-file-name-and-location-and-overwrite-existing/38275961#38275961) question in regards to tar over ssh.

The question now has an answer, and I am now asking a different question.

I run the following command to push code from my local machine to my server where it will run.

```
tar -cJf - ./my_folder | ssh user@example 'tar -xJf - -C ./path-to-my_folder/'
```

I know that with `ssh`/`scp` I can use `sshpass -p password` to stop the command asking for my password each time. **Note that I cannot use alternative methods of authentication.**

Is it possible to combine `sshpass` with my above command so that I do not have to enter my password continually?

In other words **how should I edit the above command to include `sshpass`** so that I **do not have to type in my password each time the above command runs?**

## Edit: Note the following does work

For example

```
sshpass -p <password> ssh ... blaa blaa
sshpass -p <password> scp ... blaa blaa
```

Comment: Have you looked at the following post on askubuntu, http://askubuntu.com/questions/282319/how-to-use-sshpass?

Comment: @mattias I had not seen it but it doesn't seem to be relevant?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question then. You are aware of how to use sshpass, so what is the problem?

Comment: @mattias I don't understand how to use it in this context.

Comment: ie; How do I combine `sshpass` with piping a tar contents over `ssh`.

Comment: What do you mean, "I cannot use alternative methods of authentication"? Unless the remote server actively *prevents* authentication via any means other than a password (which seems like a very dumb idea), you can always set up public key authentication for the account.

Comment: Are you *really* running a command with the remote user's password as a command-line argument?  You do know that means everyone logged onto the machine only has to run the `ps` command to see that password?

Comment: @chepner I don't know what this poster's issue is, but I work with a client running IBM Complete FTP, and all my attempts to use PK authentication failed, so we're using sshpass.

Comment: @chepner Yep. Public/private RSA keys are banned

Comment: @AndrewHenle Thanks for letting me know about this rather unfortunate security flaw

Comment: @chepner - you wouldn't believe it. Where I work, they dislike public key authentication. Their argument is that public key can be stolen remotely whereas passwords can only be stolen when someone's standing behind you.

Comment: @alvits Or if someone types in top, ps, ... do they not think of these things? To me it wasn't obvious that ps/top could be used to steal your password but it is surely obvious that not allowing authentication by RSA is a stupid thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use something like this:

```
tar -cJf - ./my_folder | sshpass -p $remote_ssh_password ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $remote_ssh_username@$remote_web_address "tar -xJf - -C ./path-to-my_folder/"
```

Note: StrictHostKeyChecking=no for avoiding prompt for server's fingerprint confirmation. It could create a security issue:

"Therefore, if you want to know whether you are talking to the right server (and not some impersonator), then you "just" need to compute the server's key fingerprint (from the public key that the server just sent to you) and compare it with a "reference fingerprint"."

More info can be found on [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/61738)

Comment: But why the strict host key checking thing?

Comment: @user3728501 - `StrictHostKeyChecking=no` will not ask to accept the host key if itsn't in `known_hosts` yet. Without it, the script will pause and ask for acceptance which `sshpass` could misinterpret.

Comment: @user3728501 you are welcome. alvits already replied about why stricthostkeychecking. please don't forget to accept answer if it's works.

Comment: Don't do that removing Host Key Checking. This is the only thing that protects you against MiTM. Verify the key by hand and it will work the same way even with host key checking and you will be safe (better than sorry).

Comment: @Jakuje this is for avoiding prompt. exactly what he asked. If you are going to evaluate this for security why not using rsa ? no need for downvote.

Comment: At least a note about the security would not hurt. This is how people learn things wrong. In some cases, the use is acceptable, but not in all of them.

Comment: @user3728501 if the answer worked for you. you may consider accepting the answer. Here is the detailed info why and how http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/178726